# How do I update/add item to a JSON array in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase data structure:

```
"Group" : {
   "34923493" : {
   "Name" : "Group 1"
   "Users" : {
       joeshmoe : true
       janedoe : true
     }
  etc..... 
  }
}
```

I want to add the following to the "Users" portion:

```
 johndoe : true
```

As the user has joined the group. I have the following code

```
self.ref.child("Group").child(groupID!).child("Users").setValue([user?.username : true])
```

but I get the following error:

```
"Contextual type'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal"
```

I am not sure what I an doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong in your code.

1. The error you're getting is most likely caused by the member variable `username` being of type `Any`. So, simply downcast it to `String`

   ```
   [user?.username as! String: true]
   ```
2. This line

   ```
   self.ref.child("Group").child(groupID!).child("Users").setValue([user?.username : true])
   ```

   will delete all the other users from the dictionary. You'd be sort of assigning `[user?.username: true]` to that child, deleting the dictionary value that is already there.
   Update the dictionary key directly instead as follows:

   ```
   self.ref.child("Group").child(groupID!).child("Users").child(user?.username as! String).setValue(true)
   ```